# Modifying string in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a text file to store the last time data was pulled from an API.

After I check if new data should be pulled I am updating the last datapoint with this Python 2.7 code:

```
if pullAgain == True:
  # open last time again
  lasttimedata = open('lasttimemultiple.txt', 'a+')  
  for item in splitData:
      if item[0:2] == PullType: 
          #formats the data point
          newTime = PullType + ':' + currenttime 
          #trying to write that data point to the spot of the old point.
          lasttimedata.write(newTime) 
          print('We updated the last time')

lasttimedata.close()  # close last time
```

I'm looking to replace the old point with the new point that this code generates. I can not figure out how to update the `splitdata[item]` position with a variable. Because `splitdata` is a list I can not reference this spot with anything but an integer.

**EDIT:**

The goal of this code is to update the `splitdata[item]` value in the list `splitdata`. The issue is I can not use `item` as an index because `item` is not an integer.

**EDIT 2:**

For example,

```
splitdata = ['00:23:15:42','01:15:12:54','02:12:23:54']
```

I'm looking to replace the item with the newly generated point

**EDIT 3:**

Here is the whole method:

```
#Pull type is the piece of data being pulled, 
# capability to Have 99 types, current default is 00.
def PullAgain(PullType): 

# This is the variable that decides if the API is called 
# again, True = pull data again.
pullAgain = False 

# Calls the local time
s1=time.localtime() 

#takes the hours, minutes and seconds out of the time
currenttime = str(s1[3])+':'+str(s1[4])+':'+str(s1[5]) 

#opens the file that contains the last time run
timefile = open('lasttimemultiple.txt','r+')

#reads the last time file
rawfile = timefile.read()

#splits the string into each individual row
splitData = string.split(rawfile,'\n') 

#closes last time
timefile.close() 
lasttime = "05:06:12"

for item in splitData:
    if item[0:2] ==  PullType:
        lasttime = str(item[3:])
        print('We made it into the if statement')

print lasttime

#this is the time formatting
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

#calculates the difference in times    
delta = (
  datetime.strptime(currenttime, FMT) - 
  datetime.strptime(lasttime, FMT))

#converts the difference into a string
tdelta = str(delta) 
print 'this is tdelta before edit:',tdelta

if tdelta[0] =='-':
    tdelta = tdelta[8:]
    print 'tdelta time has been adjusted', tdelta

#if more than 0 hours apart
if int(tdelta[0])>0:
    #Then call api again
    pullAgain = True 
elif int(tdelta[2])>=3: 
    #if time is greater than 29 sec call api again
    pullAgain = True
else:
    pullAgain = False
    print('New data not pulled, the time elapsed since last pull was: '),tdelta

splitData2 = []

if pullAgain == True:
    # open last time again
    lasttimedata = open('lasttimemultiple.txt', 'a+')  
    for item in splitData:
        if item[0:2] == PullType:
            newTime = PullType + ':' + currenttime
            splitData2.append(item)
            lasttimedata.write(splitData2)
            print('We updated the last time')

    lasttimedata.close()  # close last time

return pullAgain#return the decission to pull again or not
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, do you want to edit some value in your splitData list?

Comment: I just updated my inital post to try to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You were first asking for editing a list.

There is two ways for doing that:

**Keep a counter to know witch element to edit:**

```
for index, item in enumerate(splitData):
    splitData[item] = new_value
```

But your are editing the list while iterating, and that is not always a great idea.

**Create an output list will the element you want:**

```
output_list = []
for item in splitData:
    if i_want_to_keep:
        output_list.append(item)
    else:
        output_list.append(new_value)
```

### Then you are asking to put write that list in a file.

I think that the best way of doing it is:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for element in my_list:
        f.write(element)
```

### To finish with your question.

Please consider this code:

```
splitData2 = []
if pullAgain == True:
    # Change in splitData all the times that need to be update
    for item in splitData:
        newTime = PullType + ':' + currenttime
        if item[0:2] == PullType:
            splitData2.append(newTime)
            print('We updated the last time')

    # ReWrite the whole file with the whole data from splitData2
    with open('lasttimemultiple.txt', 'w')  as f:
        for item in splitData2:
            f.write(item)
```

1. In the first part we create a new list that contain every non-changed and new values.
2. Then we write the content of this list in the file overwriting what was already there (the non-updates datas)

I Hope that is going to help.

Comment: I didn't think about doing it this way! Thanks a bunch @Xavier

Comment: the issue with this @Xavier is append just added the value onto the end of the list, I want to replace the old data point with the new one. so the new data will go into position [item]

Comment: The solutions that I've exposed only update the list, what else do you want to update?

Comment: I'm looking to generate an new value, and replace its predecessor in the list, in the same row.

Comment: In the list or in the file, because this is quite ambiguous in your snippet.

Comment: Looking to replace the value in the list, then write that to the file. Doing my best to make this clear, really new to programming, so I dont know much of the terminology.

Comment: And from where comes that list ? Does the list contains all the data inside the file ? You might want to separate the update of the list and the update of the file.

Comment: The list is opened earlier in the code and saved to split data. I reopen it in the posted code to write the new files to it.

Comment: Ok so tell me if I understand. At the start of your code, you open the file 'lasttimemultiple.txt' ans save it's content in the list lasttimedata. Then you operate some change in lasttimedata. Finally you want to write back the list in the file.

Comment: That is correct, I have included the rest of the method, so you can see the way it is being used. The goal is to check if the data was pulled in the last 30 minutes.

Comment: I've edit my answer, If that doesn't fit your need, please consider opening a new topic with a proper question.